# В чем заключается ошибка в этом коде? Приложение на PYTHON

Tags: python

Решил написать программу по выводу погоды в приложении. Не выводит в приложении погоду.

```
import eel
import pyowm

owm = pyowm.OWM("d8c8ffd64019538a34c601513e921203")

@eel.expose
def get_weather(place):
    mgr = owm.weather_manager()
    observation = mgr.weather_at_place(place)
    w = observation.weather
    temp = w.temperature('celsius')['temp']
    return 'В городе' + place + 'сейчас' + str(temp) + 'градусов!'


    eel.init('web')
    eel.start('main.html', size=(700, 700))
```

---

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Погода</title>
    <script src="eel.js"></script>
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="/favicon.png">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:wght@300;400;500&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>

    <input id="location" type="text" placeholder="Введите назавание страны и города..."
    required="" value="Нью-Йорк, США">
    <button id="show">Узнать погоду</button>

    <div class="info"></div>

   <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    async function display_weather(){
        let city = document.getElementById('location').value;
        let res = await eel.get_weather(city)();
        document.getElementById('info').innerHTML = res;
    }
    jQuery ('#show').on('click', function(){
        display_weather();
    });

    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: а где собственно вызов `eel.get_weather(...)` ?

Comment: Так вроде в модулее eel нет этого атрибута

Comment: а зачем же вы тогда декоратор `@eel.expose` вызываете??

Comment: Для JavaScript' a

Comment: Понял ошибку. Забыл обернуть этот скрипт в вывод информации